# My given code does not print the last input value. What is wrong with the code?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the film");
        String str = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the film budget");
        int a = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the running time");
        double b = s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the film production house");
        String str1 = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Film being screened : " + str);
        System.out.printf("Budget : %d crores", a);
        System.out.printf("\nRunning time : %.2f hours", b);
        System.out.printf("\nProduction : %s", str1);
    }
}
```

I am getting input for a string, integer, double and again string. However, I am not able to get the "Production" value that I enter.

Comment: String str1 = s.next(); use this insted

Comment: I tried that, but while printing it does not print input values that are followed by space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do

```
System.out.println("Enter the film production house");
s.nextLine();
String str1 = s.nextLine();
```

This is because s.nextDouble() doesn't consume the *last newline character* of your input so str1 is assigned a "\n" (new line) value